# How to have a Windows Service wait efficiently for RabbitMQ to become available

Tags: c#, multithreading, rabbitmq

Threads on a multi threaded windows service (aka serviceA) want to wait for RabbitMQ to become available. RabbitMQ may be turned on or off at any point in time while serviceA is running. What is the best way to wait for RabbitMQ to become available?

Should each thread set a timer for an interval - when the timer has elapsed, check to see if it can connect again?

A while loop would be processor intensive.

Thread.Sleep() can prevent the Windows service from stopping.

Thread.SpinWait() seems to be CPU intensive.

In addition, what if:

1. RabbitMQ service is stopped
2. serviceA is then started
3. 10 minutes later, or 3 days later, RabbitMQ service is started

Answer (score 0):

how about register callback with `task` and use async method from RabbitMQ Client, i understand Rabbit support asynchronous message handler using `AsyncEventingBasicConsumer`

you can check on [Handle RabbitMQ in async way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836811/rabbitmq-handle-received-message-in-async-way)

Comment: Sorry I tried to elaborate after seeing your response. What if RabbitMQ is unavailable at the time I start my service?